# How to check what's causing write() syscall to hang? Python subprocesses stop working after a while

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, system-calls, strace

Here's what the strace results look like for when the Python script is working properly. Both the main process (412) and its subprocesses are working as intended. However, after a while, maybe 40-60 minutes later, the subprocesses start to fail and cannot successfully make write calls.

```
strace: Process 1693 attached
[pid  1693] close(4)                    = 0 <0.000028>
[pid  1693] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 4 <0.000077>
[pid  1693] write(1, "options ['Forex']\n", 18) = 18 <0.000048>
[pid  1693] openat(AT_FDCWD, "csv/forex_settings.json", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 6 <0.000064>
[pid  1693] read(6, "{\"feature\": \"Stocks\", \"speed\": \""..., 348) = 347 <0.000034>
[pid  1693] read(6, "", 1)              = 0 <0.000025>
[pid  1693] close(6)                    = 0 <0.000039>
[pid  1693] openat(AT_FDCWD, "feature_titles/forex.png", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 6 <0.000062>
[pid  1693] read(6, "\211PNG\r\n\32\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0`\0\0\0 \4\3\0\0\0\37\356`"..., 4096) = 388 <0.000035>
[pid   412] close(5)                    = 0 <0.000064>
[pid   412] openat(AT_FDCWD, "csv/crypto_settings.json", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 5 <0.000143>
[pid   412] read(5, "{\"feature\": \"Stocks\", \"speed\": \""..., 349) = 348 <0.000060>
[pid   412] read(5, "", 1)              = 0 <0.000040>
[pid   412] close(5)                    = 0 <0.000097>
[pid   412] openat(AT_FDCWD, "./display_images/Crypto.ppm", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 5 <0.000125>
[pid  1693] close(6)                    = 0 <0.000027>
[pid   412] read(5, "P6\n569 32\n255\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000052>
[pid  1693] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/pi/logos/stocks/down-1.png", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 6 <0.000154>
[pid   412] read(5, "P6\n569 32\n255\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000073>
[pid   412] read(5,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1693] read(6, "\211PNG\r\n\32\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\16\4\3\0\0\0\324\1\201"..., 4096) = 199 <0.000035>
[pid   412] <... read resumed> "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 61440) = 50542 <0.000554>
[pid   412] read(5, "", 8192)           = 0 <0.000047>
[pid   412] close(5)                    = 0 <0.000095>
[pid  1693] close(6)                    = 0 <0.000044>
[pid  1693] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/pi/logos/currencies/EUR.png", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 6 <0.000074>
[pid  1693] read(6, "\211PNG\r\n\32\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\26\10\3\0\0\0\363j\234"..., 4096) = 968 <0.000040>
[pid  1693] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/pi/logos/currencies/USD.png", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 7 <0.000146>
[pid  1693] read(7, "\211PNG\r\n\32\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\26\10\3\0\0\0\363j\234"..., 4096) = 984 <0.000038>
[pid  1693] close(7)                    = 0 <0.000056>
[pid  1693] close(6)                    = 0 <0.000042>
[pid  1693] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/pi/logos/stocks/up-1.png", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 6 <0.000068>
[pid  1693] read(6, "\211PNG\r\n\32\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\16\4\3\0\0\0\324\1\201"..., 4096) = 192 <0.000039>
[pid  1693] close(6)                    = 0 <0.000045>
[pid  1693] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/pi/logos/currencies/USD.png", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 6 <0.000112>
[pid  1693] read(6, "\211PNG\r\n\32\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\26\10\3\0\0\0\363j\234"..., 4096) = 984 <0.000039>
[pid  1693] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/pi/logos/currencies/JPY.png", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 7 <0.000151>
[pid  1693] read(7, "\211PNG\r\n\32\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\26\10\3\0\0\0\363j\234"..., 4096) = 769 <0.000047>
[pid  1693] close(7)                    = 0 <0.000060>
[pid  1693] close(6)                    = 0 <0.000043>
[pid  1693] openat(AT_FDCWD, "./display_images/Forex.ppm", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 6 <0.000359>
[pid  1693] write(6, "P6\n507 32\n255\n", 14) = 14 <0.000104>
[pid  1693] write(6, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 48672) = 48672 <0.000269>
[pid  1693] close(6)                    = 0 <0.000400>
[pid  1693] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid   412] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1693, si_uid=1, si_status=0, si_utime=5, si_stime=9} ---
[pid   412] close(4)                    = 0 <0.000064>
```

About 40-60 minutes later of running the Python script, here are the strace results. PID 2220 seems to be stuck with the `write(1, "options ['Forex']\n", 18 <unfinished ...>` syscall? How can I check what is causing it to hang?

```
strace: Process 2220 attached
[pid   412] close(5)                    = 0 <0.000048>
[pid   412] openat(AT_FDCWD, "csv/crypto_settings.json", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 5 <0.000163>
[pid   412] read(5, "{\"feature\": \"Stocks\", \"speed\": \""..., 349) = 348 <0.000071>
[pid  2220] close(4 <unfinished ...>
[pid   412] read(5,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2220] <... close resumed> )       = 0 <0.000083>
[pid   412] <... read resumed> "", 1)   = 0 <0.000105>
[pid  2220] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid   412] close(5 <unfinished ...>
[pid  2220] <... openat resumed> )      = 4 <0.000137>
[pid   412] <... close resumed> )       = 0 <0.000136>
[pid   412] openat(AT_FDCWD, "./display_images/Crypto.ppm", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 5 <0.000099>
[pid   412] read(5, "P6\n569 32\n255\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000046>
[pid  2220] write(1, "options ['Forex']\n", 18 <unfinished ...>
[pid   412] read(5, "P6\n569 32\n255\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096 <0.000079>
[pid   412] read(5, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 61440) = 50542 <0.000322>
[pid   412] read(5, "", 8192)           = 0 <0.000067>
[pid   412] close(5)                    = 0 <0.000048>
[pid  2220] <... write resumed> )       = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <9.479316>
[pid  2220] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=412, si_uid=1} ---
[pid  2220] +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
[pid   412] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=2220, si_uid=1, si_status=SIGTERM, si_utime=0, si_stime=1} ---
[pid   412] close(4)                    = 0 <0.000218>
```

Is there a way for me to check what is causing the write call to be hanging? Thanks.

Comment: did you find the solution to this? I am also facing same issue

Comment: please add a reproducible example of your `subprocess` call code!

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the `strace` output, it looks like the `write` targets the standard output of the process (file descriptor number `1`). That file descriptor is associated with a pipe. Effectively, a pipe is a fixed-size buffer that can be written to and read from. Whenever the buffer is full or the `write` request is larger than the remaining buffer size, the system call blocks until the other side reads enough data to make room for the write request.

As long as the buffer is not full, `write` does not block. Even if the other end does not read any data, the application continues to work until the remaining buffer size is too small for the `write` request.

The actual buffer size of a pipe varies across operating systems. On Linux, the default is `16` pages, which translates to `65536` on most platforms. The buffer size can be changed by means of `fcntl`.

Usually, the buffer size associated with a pipe is not the issue but making sure that data is read to keep the other end from blocking is.